# How to get text to input to a newline in a text widget in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I am creating a simple program that displays text on a listbox in tkinter. Sometimes the text that I want to display is larger then the listbox so it goes off the screen. I was wondering if there was a way to get the text to start a new line below instead of going off the screen.

> Code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root, width = 50, height=15, bg="#2C2F33", fg="white",wrap=WORD)
text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)

while True:
    message = input("Enter a message: ")
    text.insert(INSERT, message)

root.mainloop()
```

> Problem:

[image: The messages are not inputting on a newline]

> Intended result

[image: The intended result]

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: why are u using a listbox in this example, it is usually used for menu list ? It is not possible for a listbox item to be spread across more than one line or row.

Comment: I am fairly new to tkinter and I found that a listbox was the best way for me to display multiple items. I do not need to select anything I just want a scrollable area that will display messages. Do you know of another widget that is capable of doing what I am asking?

Comment: you should start with widget Text, thats what you are looking for :)

Comment: check edit of my post ;)

Comment: It seems to have worked! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: you should set option wrap=WORD

Comment: Youre welcome. Im glad that I hepled :)

Comment: One more question, How do I get the text widget to input to a newline each time a message comes in. Say I have a message2 that needs to be inputted.

Comment: '\n' will do the job. add it on the end of the previous message, or efore new messaage

Comment: @ncica The messages are variables so I cannot add \n.

Comment: can you open a new questions with some examples it will be easier to help you

Comment: @ncica I edited the queston.

Comment: text.insert(INSERT, str(message) + '\n')

Comment: Thank you, I got everything to work! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Youre welcome. Im glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Listbox widget is a menu of items to choose from. It is not possible for a listbox item to be spread across more than one line or row.

you should use another widget called Text

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
message = "This message is too long to display on the listbox. I hope that someone will help me find a solution to this problem."
text = Text(root, width = 50, height=15, bg="#2C2F33", fg="white",wrap=WORD)

text.insert(INSERT, message)

text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

> note:
>   **wrap** : This option controls the display of lines that are too wide. Set wrap=WORD and it will break the line after the last word
>   that will fit. With the default behavior, wrap=CHAR, any line that
>   gets too long will be broken at any character.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can already scroll without a scrollbar. Is there any other widget that can replace the listbox that is capable of doing what I am asking?